# View PDF document in JavaFx programme

Tags: javafx

I want to view pdf document already saved in the hard disk using JavaFX by clicking the table view button, I used the below code for update data. I made a button, but I couldn't make the function for the view of the pdf. could you please help me? thank you...

```
public void loadTpnTable(ObservableList<TPN> obList) {

       colDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("date"));
       colTpnno.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tpnno"));
       colSubject.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("subject")); 
       tblTpn.setItems(tpnList);

    //create callback instance
    Callback<TableColumn<TPN, Void>, TableCell<TPN, Void>> updateFactory
            = new Callback<TableColumn<TPN, Void>, TableCell<TPN, Void>>() {

        @Override
        //create new cell
        public TableCell<TPN, Void> call(TableColumn<TPN, Void> param) {
            final TableCell<TPN, Void> updateCell = new TableCell<TPN, Void>() {

                private final Button btnUpdate = new Button("Update");

                {
                    btnUpdate.setOnAction((ActionEvent a) -> {
                        //select row
                        int rowIndex = getTableRow().getIndex();
                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(rowIndex);

                        updateTpn = getTableView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                        txtTpnno.setText(updateTpn.getTpnno());
                        txtSubject.setText(updateTpn.getSubject());



                        updateMode();           //disable save button and enable update button
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Void item, boolean b) {

                    super.updateItem(item, b);
                    if (b) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(btnUpdate);
                    }
                }
            };

            return updateCell;
        }
    };

 Callback<TableColumn<TPN, Void>, TableCell<TPN, Void>> openFactory  //deleteFactory
            = new Callback<TableColumn<TPN, Void>, TableCell<TPN, Void>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<TPN, Void> call(TableColumn<TPN, Void> param) {
            final TableCell<TPN, Void> openCell = new TableCell<TPN, Void>() {

                private final Button btnOpen = new Button("Open");

                {
                    btnOpen.setOnAction((ActionEvent a) -> {
                        //select row
                        int rowIndex = getTableRow().getIndex();
                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(rowIndex);
```

Comment: What's a TPN? At a glance, I don't see anything having to do with a pdf file.

Comment: TPN is a PDF document category

Comment: There really isn't enough information to help. You need to create a complete contained example. What part do you need help with? Displaying a pdf? Opening a window when you click a button? Doing anything when you click a button?

Comment: I want to open pdf file when i click the button in table view

Comment: This is a document management system. First, it saves the pdf documents details and pdf document as a blob type. I want to open that saved pdf document through this system. That is my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I use Apache PDFBox for that purpose. I have prepared a little demo how that can be used in JavaFX some time ago which can be found here: https://github.com/mipastgt/JFXToolsAndDemos/tree/master/jfxtools-awtimage-demos/src/main/java/de/mpmediasoft/jfxtools/awtimage/demo