# using Apache PDFbox.java instead of sun,pdfview.java

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdfview

I am working on a project that does some processes on PDFs and this project used package com.sun.pdfview;
My job now is to make these functions works depending on
Apache PDFbox library
I need to use a class similar to ThumbPanel.java using the Apache PDFbox library

I tried to look for a similar class using the PDFbox but i could not find any similarity

Comment: There isn't, but maybe have a look at this project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503120/view-pdf-document-in-javafx-programme/61506283#61506283

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wow I didn't even know that sun released some kind of PDF lib. Read some stuff about it in the [webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170410014956/https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer)... But besides that what does the ThumbPanel.java do?

Comment: It shows thumbnails on the left panel. IMHO if Fadi doesn't have to care about the licensing then he should copy the source code and combine it with the PDFBox rendering API.